# django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist:/hello/

Tags: python, django

I created a function hello>view.py

```
def index (request):
    return render(request,"hello/index.html")
```

and an HTML file in hello>template>hello>index.html,
but the is what I've got

```
Internal Server Error: /hello/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/douju/lecture3/hello/views.py", line 7, in index
    return render(request,"hello/index.html")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: hello/index.html
```

this is what in my TEMPLETS:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Please check if you are storing your templates in the same directory as mentioned in your settings.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have created a **template** folder when you need a **templates** (note the S at the end).

Comment: Wow, it works! I don't know the folder name matters

Answer (score 0):

Django should automatically search through templates located in each `INSTALLED_APP`'s `templates/` directory. If Django isn't finding the templates, you may have `TEMPLATES['APP_DIRS']=False` in your `settings.py`. If it still isn't finding your template files, consider specifying additional template directories using the `TEMPLATES['DIRS']` setting:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "myapp/somefolder/templates")],  # Specify a non standard template directory
        "APP_DIRS": True,  # Make sure this is True
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Django Template Settings: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#templates